# Mostrar número de aprobados y media de una secuencia de números enteros dada por teclado

Tags: c++

Necesito crear un programa en C++ que dada una secuencia de números por teclado que corresponde a las notas de varias asignaturas (empieza con el código de la primera y muestra sus notas, y al introducir un -1 pasa a la siguiente asignatura, y al recibir un 0 acaba la secuencia) muestre en pantalla cuál es la que tiene un mayor número de aprobados y su nota media. Mi gran problema es cómo programar que el primer número es el código y separarlo de las notas para encajarlo todo, hacer la media, calcularlo todo y mostrarlo en pantalla. Igual se puede hacer con arrays pero no es el objetivo. No será muy difícil pero soy nuevo en esto.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const double FINAL = 0;
const double FIN_ASIGNATURA = -1;

int main()
{
    double sumatorio = 0.0;
    double numero = 0.0;
    int n = 0;
    int codigo_asignatura = 0;
    int notas_aprobadas = 0;
    double media = 0.0;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    cout << "Escribe el código y las notas de la asignatura (" << FINAL << "-> Acabar): " << endl;
    cin >> numero;

    while (numero != FINAL){
        while (numero != FIN_ASIGNATURA) {
            sumatorio = sumatorio + numero;
            n++;
            cin >> numero;
            media = sumatorio / n;

            if(numero >= 5 && numero <= 10){
                notas_aprobadas ++;
            }

    }
        if(numero > 10){
            cin >> codigo_asignatura;
        }
    }

    cout << "Asignatura con mayor número de aprobados = " << "" << endl; // tengo que definir la variable de mayor numero de aprobados en ""
    cout << "Nota media = " << media << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas dos bucles:

- uno para introducir las asignaturas
- otro para las notas

En cada uno de ellos evaluas la condición de finalización

- el bucle de asignaturas termina al recibir un 0
- el bucle de notas termina cuando se introduce un -1

Expresado en código, podrías tener algo así:

```
int asignatura;
std::cin >> asignatura;
while(asignatura != 0)
{
    int nota;
    std::cin >> nota;
    while (nota != -1)
    {
        // operaciones con la nota ...

        std::cin >> nota;
    }

    std::cin >> asignatura;
}
```